# Reduce our problem to a known np-complete problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, decision-problem

Subgraph isomorphism

We have the graphs $G_1=(V_1,E_1), G_2=(V_2,E_2)$.

Question: Is the graph G_1 isomorphic with a subgraph of $G_2$ ?

(i.e. is there a subset of vertices of $G_2, V \subseteq V_2$ and subset of the edges of $G_2 E \subseteq E_2$ such that $|V|=|V_1|$ and $|E|=|E_1|$ and is there a one-to-one matching of the vertices of $G_1$ at the subset of vertices $V$ of $G_2 f:V_1 \to V$ such that $\{u,v\} \in E_1 \Leftrightarrow \{ f(u),f(v) \} \in E$)

In order to show that the problem is in NP, could we say the following?

A non-deterministic Turing machine can first "guess" which subgraph $G$ of $G_2$ is isomorphic with $G_1$ and then verify that $G$ is isomorphic with $G$ in $O(V_1+E_1)$ steps, since if we assume that the graphs are represented as adjacency lists, $G_1$ will have $O(V_1+E_1)$ elements.

Or could I improve something?

I want to show that the problem is NP-complete, reducing the clique problem to it (Hint: assume that  the graph $G_1$ is complete)

Could you give me a hint how we could reduce the clique problem to our problem in order to show that the latter is NP-complete?

Comment: Your verification algorithm doesn't work (at least not as specified). Graph Isomorphism is not known to have a linear time algorithm.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus How else could the verification step look like?

Comment: @evinda You need a stronger certificate (or: "guess" more).

Comment: What more could we guess for example? @TomvanderZanden

Comment: @evinda Something that helps you determine whether the subgraph is indeed isomorphic. (Note: there is no known polynomial algorithm for graph isomorphism, as Yuval noted you can't just say you can check this in linear time.)

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Could we justify as follows that the problem is in NP? Or could I improve something?
$$$$
A non-deterministic Turing machine first "guesses" the subset of nodes $V$ and the subset of edges $E$ of $G_2$ and after that it verifies that $|V|=|V_1|$ and $|E|=|E_1|$ and that there is a one-to-one correspondence $f:V_1 \to V$ such that $\{u,v\} \in E_1 \Leftrightarrow \{ f(u), f(v) \} \in E$. Since there are $O(n^2)$ different pairs of vertices, the check requires polynomial time. So the problem belongs in NP.

Comment: How exactly do you check that there is a one-to-one correspondence? Your argumentation (that this supposedly is polynomial time) is insufficient. There are far more one-to-one correspondences than there are pairs of vertices.

Comment: an active research area; coincidentally here is a recent survey/ new results. citations in here will point to NP completeness proofs. [The Hardness of Subgraph Isomorphism](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.02876v1.pdf) / Cygan, Pachocki, Socala

Answer (score 5):

The **hint** tells you pretty much everything:

Consider an arbitrary graph $G_{2}$ on $n$ vertices. 
Also per the suggestion of the hint, let $G_1$ be the complete graph on $k$ vertices, for some $k \le n$.

*Is $G_{1}$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $G_{2}$?*

- If yes, what does that tell you about $G_{2}$?
- How can you use that to solve the max-clique problem?

Comment: If $G_1$ is isomorhic to a subgraph of $G_1$, don't we deduce from the fact that $G_1$ is a complete graph on $k$ vertices, that $G_2$ contains a complete subgraph of $k$ vertices?
$$$$
I found the following: "A maximum clique of a graph, G, is a clique, such that there is no clique with more vertices.".

So in order to solve the max-clique problem, do we assume that all the $k$ vertices of the subgraph of $G_2$ are connected to each other but all the $n-k+1$ remaining vertices aren't connected to any other vertex? Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: A clique of size $k$ **is** a complete graph on $k$ vertices. As you said, if $G_{1}$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $G_{2}$, then we conclude that $G_{2}$ contains a clique of size $k$. How can you check if $G_{2}$ contains a clique of size $k+1$?

Comment: If $G_2$ would contain a clique of size $k+1$, then $G_2$ couldn't contain a clique of size $k$ that is isomorphic with $G_1$ because the $k+1$-th element of the clique of size $k+1$ would be adjacent to all the other vertices of the graph and so the clique of size $k$ of the graph $G_2$ will have more edges than the graph $G_1$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: No, that is not correct. If $G_{2}$ contains a clique of size $k+1$, then it will also contain (many) subgraphs that are isomorphic to a complete graph on $k$ vertices. Take a step back; the answer is right in front of you!
We have a *black box* to check if a graph $G_{2}$ contains a clique of size $k$. (What is $k$? -- Any number you want, right?). Lets say that $G_{2}$ contains a max clique of size $9$. We know that this is the max clique if $G_{2}$ does *not* contain a clique of size $10, \dots, n$. But we *already* have a black box to check that. Do you see it now?

Comment: If $G_2$ contains a clique of size $k+1$ will it necessarily contain many subgraphs that are isomorhic to a complete graph on $k$ vertices? If so, could you explain me why?
$$$$
Also, we have a black box to check if a graph contains a clique of size $k$. So in order to determine if $G_2$ contains a clique of size $k+1$, we will ask the black box, right?
$$$$
$G_2$ contains a max clique of size $V_2$, right?
$$$$
So, in order to solve the max-clique problem, do we have to assume that  $G_1$ is a complete graph on $n$ vertices and check if $G_1$ is isomorphic to $G_2$ ?

Comment: If $G_{2}$ contains a clique of size $k+1$, then contains $k+1$ vertices all connected to each other. If you ignore any of the $k+1$ vertices, you are left with $k$ vertices all connected to each other. So a $k+1$ clique contains many $k$-cliques. 

For the subsequent questions, if you create $G_{1}$ to be a complete graph on $n$ vertices and use the black box, then you check if $G_{2}$ has clique on $n$ vertices, *i.e*, if $G_{2}$ is the complete graph itself. If it is, then clearly the max clique has size $n$. What if it is not?

Comment: Couldn't we also just use the clique problem as say he following?
$$$$
Let $(G,k)$ a random instance of the clique problem.
$$$$
We can construct an instance of the Subgraph isomorphism problem in polynomial time as follows:
$$$$
$G_2$ is a graph on $n$ vertices.
$$$$
$G_1$ is a complete graph on $k$ vertices, for some $k \leq n$.
$$$$
$G$ corresponds to the graph $G_2$.
$$$$
The problem Subgraph Isomorphism has a solution iff there is a comple subgraph of $G_2$ with $k$ vertices, i.e. iff the graph $G$ has a complete subgraph with $k$ vertices.

Comment: Thus, the instance of the problem Subgraph Isomorphism has a solution iff the initial instance of the problem Clique has a solution.

Comment: Or could I improve something, megas?

Comment: It seems you are getting the idea. I am not sure what you mean by a (G,k) random instance of the clique problem? First observe that if we can answer the question "Does G contain a clique of size k? (for arbitrary k), then we can solve the MaxClique problem. Why? We can ask that for all k=1,…,n and find the largest k for which G contains a k-clique. So if we can efficiently answer the question for arbitrary k, you can solve the MaxClique with n (so, polynomial number of) calls.

Comment: Now, you have to carefully describe the reduction.
If you are given any (arbitrary) instance of the MaxClique problem, or equivalently as argued above, a graph $G$ and an arbitrary parameters $k$ and seek whether $G$ contains a clique of size $k$, you must describe how to construct the instance of the Subraph Isomorphism (SI) problem. $G_{2}$ is indeed $G$. $G_{1}$ is a complete graph on $k$ vertices where $k$ is the one specified in the input (not *some* $k$). Finally, don't forget to argue that the reduction (construction of the SI instance) takes polynomial time.